# Docker slave is not a JNLP agent issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jnlp, docker-machine

we are using **jenkinsci/slave** image to create slave in jenkins but while executing curl command facing below issue in that container slave

```
INFO: [JNLP4-connect connection to 172.16.102.234/172.16.102.234:4000] Local headers refused by remote: docker-slave-7d0fa4f1f330 is not a JNLP agent
Sep 21, 2017 9:28:34 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: docker-slave-7d0fa4f1f330 is not a JNLP agent
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:385)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
```

Please give suggestion on this

[image]

[image]

Using docker toolbox windows and jenkinsci/slave image used for slave connection in jenkins

I have published my docker engine in tcp://192.168.99.100:2376

Comment: Certificate issue (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39232)? Port non visible (80, 50000)? An agent must query the Jenkins master on both those ports.

Comment: @VonC me to facing this issue ,please explain clearly

Comment: Well, it depends on which docker you are using (version, OS? host OS?) and what port you have published? (and if you need to port-forward them if you are not on Linux)

Comment: @VonC i have comment below.please find the details

Comment: You cannot "comment" below: below is for answers only. Edit your question.

Comment: @VonC sorry ,deleted now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155065/discussion-between-vijay-and-vonc).